# Defining global variables according to whether or not Xcode UI tests are running

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

How can I define *global* variables according to whether or not Xcode UI Tests are running? I'm trying to do this:

```
#if UITESTS
    let api = StubbedAPI()
#else 
    let api = RealAPI()
#endif
```

These are global variables, so I can't call `NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment` or `NSProcessInfo.processInfo().arguments` at file scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The UI Testing target runs as a separate process from your application. This means you can't set preprocessor macros in the test target and expect the app to know about them. The only way the tests can communicate with the app is via the two `processInfo` settings you mention.

Using these is dynamic, whereas your proposed solution is static. However, it is still possible to do what you are trying to do with the tools Apple has given us.

First, create a protocol that both StubbedAPI and RealAPI conform to.

```
protocol API {
    // ... //
}

class RealAPI: API {
    // ... //
}

class StubbedAPI: API {
    // ... //
}
```

Next, create a configuration class. This will be used to tell your code which API to use at run time.

```
struct Config {
    var api: APIProtocol { 
        get { 
            return UITesting() ? RealAPI() : StubbedAPI()
        }
    }
}

private func UITesting() -> Bool {
    return NSProcessInfo.processInfo().arguments.contains("UI-TESTING")
}
```

Then, retrieve a reference to an implementation of API via the configuration.

```
class FooService {
    private let api = Config().api;
}
```

Finally, set the processInfo argument before you launch the app under UI Testing.

```
class UITests: TestCase {
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        app.launchArguments = ["UI-TESTING"]
        app.launch()
    }
}
```

The `api` property will be set to the real API when running production code and the stubbed one under UI Testing.

There are some downsides to this approach. First, you are introducing the actual "stubbed" API to your production code. This has the potential downside of a developer actually using this in production. Second, you are required to create the `API` protocol to only have one "real" object implement it. Unfortunately, this is the best solution I've come up with given the current state of UI Testing and Swift.